# Lines in map visually compressed due to tortuosity

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line, tortuosity

When exporting a map in ArcGIS pro,
shapefiles containing lines for jurisdictional borders that are very tortuous (e.g. around irregularly shaped lakes) get visually compressed, so the line width seems thicker than for the rest of the map.

Is there a way to fix this, preferably (but not necessarily) without simplifying the lines? Attempting to delete vertices crashes my ArcGIS pro...

[image]

Comment: I have used vertex count vs. length of lines to select the twisty ones. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011230. You could symbolize twisty lines, if they are separate features, with thinner lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have licensing access, ArcGIS Pro's Simplify Polygon is a good choice. It is in the Cartography tools>Generalization toolbox. Messing around with the parameters can produce pretty good results, and you don't have to fiddle with any vertices.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/cartography/simplify-polygon.htm